# curvature of space curve

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am slightly confused by the following curve $\gamma(t) = (e^t,0,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Its curvature, defined as
$$
\kappa(t) = \frac{\|\dot \gamma(t) \times \ddot \gamma(t)\|}{\|\dot \gamma(t)\|^3}
$$
vanishes everywhere, yet if I think about the curve geometrically it does have curvature. What  am I missing ? Do I need a unit-speed parametrization to obtain the correct result?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Your curve is contained in a straight line, the $x$-axis.

Comment: @harlekin You're probably visualizing the curve $(t,e^t,0)$.

Comment: @Sigur, the positive portion of the $x$-axis

Comment: @GitGud yes, I was - I realized this the moment you pointed it out, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your curve is exactly the interval: $(0,\infty)$ which is essentially a ray and has no curvature. Straight rays/lines have zero curvature.

Here is a cool link on [curvature](http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~cs577/handouts/curvature.pdf). 
 
(I know you know what curvature is, I just thought the link was amusing/helpful.)